# how to remove confidance interval in pairplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, pairplot

May you please help to remove the confidence interval in the seaborn pairplot.

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins,kind="reg")
```

I know it is possible in regplot or lmplot using ci=None, but I would like the same functionality in pairplot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [pair plot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html), you can pass keyword arguments that are specifically for the plot.  This should do it.

```
import seaborn as sns
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
sns.pairplot(penguins,kind="reg", plot_kws={'ci':None})
```